# Is there efficient way to deal cards other then this if statement?

Tags: c

I want to deal 52 cards numbered from 1 to 52. To share it into 4 groups of 13 cards and to separate them, I put "-" in the code below to make them appear nice. The other group starts with card numbers 14,27 and 40. I could not find a better way then 2 OR's in if statement.
What I want to ask is if there is an easier way than this.(if (cardNo==14 || cardNo==27 || cardNo==40)

```
while (cardNo<53)
{
    ...

    if (cardNo==14 || cardNo==27 || cardNo==40)
    {
        printf("------------\n");
    }

    printf("%-6s of %-6s\n ", face[column], suit[row]); 
    cardNo++;
}
```

Comment: I'd have a separate counter from 1 to 13 (or zero to 12).  Reset after each hand is dealt.

Comment: What kind of computer are you using where formatting and printing 52 lines of output is an "efficiency" concern.  But as MrB points out below, extracting the suit and value from the number with modulus and integer division would be "cleaner".

Comment: I have E8400 2GB Ram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the modulo operator:

```
if ((cardNo - 1) % 13 == 0)
```

Comment: Except that you need to beware of the 1-origin of cardNo.

Comment: Np! Glad I could help! I missed that you weren't counting from 0 :)!